# redis for ppdb resource representation

Tags: redis

There is a well known lexical resources of paraphrases [PPDB](http://paraphrase.org/).

I wonder what is the best way to represent the data in redis.

Here, every key (let assume key is a first string) has a list of similar strings, so the value should be a list, however for every string in list I need to save additional parameters, so I need as value a list of lists or a list of hashes.

It should be looking as follows

```
{'suggest':[
           {'sting':'provide','similarity':0,8},
           {'string':'offer','similarity':0,7}
           ]
}
```

where '`suggest`' is a key, and the list of hashes is the value.

Is this possible in redis to represent the data in such a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use one sorted set per word. The name of the sorted set will be the word, the members will be the similar strings and the scores will be the similarity.

```
ZADD word:suggest 0.8 provide
ZADD word:suggest 0.7 offer
```

Then you can retrieve all the words similar to "suggest" with this command:

```
ZRANGE word:suggest 0 -1
```

You can also include the scores:

```
ZRANGE word:suggest 0 -1 WITHSCORES
```

Check also all the other functions for sorted sets.

Comment: great, this will help me, but let's assume I have several similarity fields, is it possible to store them all in the list like in hash manner (not necessarly sorted set)?

Comment: What is a similarity field? Can you extend your initial example to make it more realistic?